# Basic (I think?) wp_enqueue issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to load a script called accordion.js using this:

```
function accordion() {
    wp_register_script( 
        'accordion',  
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null, 
        true 
        );
    wp_enqueue_script('accordion');
}
```

It's not loading the script (as in it doesn't appear in Resources with Chrome devtools), and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I realize this is probably very basic, but nothing I'm trying seems to fix it.

Comment: Random suggestion: try removing the jquery dependency to see if it loads it then? Also, digging into the WP code and ensuring that your script is correctly registered is a good idea. Put in debugging statements in there (and if WP core code is under version control it is very easy to revert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you've included will not work on its own (if you've dropped that into your `functions.php` file).  You'll also need to ensure that you call your function with the proper hook like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'accordion');
```

This will tell WordPress to run the `accordion` function when it's time to enqueue the scripts.

Additionally, you might want to rename your function to something more generic such as `load_resources` and you can enqueue *all* of your scripts that you'll need inside that function.

If you're doing that successfully, but you still have problems, you might check the Net tab of your developer tool and see if the browser is at least attempting to load the file (if even from the wrong location).